# JPA - Lazily loaded entity reference has its fields null

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

I am using Java 8 and Spring Data JPA with Hibernate.  I am observing a strange behaviour.

All entity relationships are LAZY loaded.

```
Course toBeMatched = //...a repository call to get a course...;

for (Student s : college.getStudents()) {
  if (s.getCourse().equals(toBeMatched)) {
    found = true;
  }
}
```

My `equals()` method returns `false` even for genuine cases.  The implementation of `Course#equals` is somewhat along these lines:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;

    Course other = (Course) obj;
    if (shortName == null) {
        if (other.shortName != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!shortName.equals(other.shortName))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

**Issue:**
My issue is that `shortName.equals(other.shortName)` fails wrongly, as `other.shortName` is always `null`, however, if I use `other.getShortName()`, I get the value correctly.

My question is whether I am doing anything fundamentally wrong by accessing fields of lazily loaded entity instead of going through its getter methods.

Comment: That is what you get when using Hibernate, using proxies instead of bytecode enhancement and consequently it is clueless about lazy loading fields since it can't detect their usage. Turn on bytecode enhancement or use a JPA provider that does it out of the box

Answer (score 3):

Hibernate ORM Returns Proxy objects and lazy loads to support caching and improve performance. Currently there is no way to intercept calls to Proxy fields thus `other.shortName` will always be `null`, Only way is to intercept calls to Proxy methods. Just like in your case the `other.getShortName()` is the way to do it.